# How do I add OpenGL Mathematics (GLM) to Xcode 4?

Tags: c++, opengl, xcode4

I can't figure out how to add the framework to my project. I tried adding it like any other framework, by clicking the plus button under Link Binary With Libraries and then clicking 'other' and then selecting the GLM folder. But when I go to included it, the autocomplete works but it can't build because it says the file is not found.

Website for library: http://glm.g-truc.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the website, it's not a framework, it's only headers. You should just add the headers directly to your project.

Comment: Ok cool, I added the header file that was in the top level of the folder (I'm assuming this is the one you're meant to add) but then that header file tries to load other header files. These header files are in a folder at the same level, but it fails to load. Any suggestion?

Comment: I just went into Xcode 4.2, right clicked on my project, and selected "Add Files to '<project name>'…". I then selected glm-0.9.3.B/glm, and it imported everything in the glm sub-folder. I added #include "glm.hpp" to one of my source files and built, and it succeeded in compiling. It did fail to link because of the file glm/dummy.cpp, which contains a main() function. But presumably if you remove that file, it should build just fine.

Comment: Though Could I ask why an include like this: `#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>`      won't work?

Comment: You shouldn't use the angle brackets ("<" and ">") for non-system or non-framework headers. Since they're part of your source and not part of an actual framework or the system, you need to use the user include style which uses quotations instead of angle brackets.

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting Match-O Link error make sure to remove/trash the core/dummy.cpp this will keep it from compiling.

Answer (score 0):

When I imported the headers in XCode 5, it tried to link glm.cpp and dummy.cpp automatically under build phase.  I removed those and now I'm compiling.

Also had to rename all my files to *.mm to compile with obj-c++.