# Adding GLM to project in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to add GLM to a project in Xcode 4, but I cannot get it to compile. I have added the glm files to my project through the add files dialog.

I get a lexical/preprocessor issue and Xcode cannot find the file `<cmath>`.

I am not sure what I need to tweak to get this to build.

I have seen [How do I add OpenGL Mathematics (GLM) to Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779430/how-do-i-add-opengl-mathematics-glm-to-xcode-4) already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add the files to the project and `#import "glm.hpp"` (for Objective-C++;  for simple C++ it should just be `#include "glm.hpp"`).

A couple things to be careful of:

- The OpenGL Mathematics library, when you download it, comes with a bunch of stuff you don't need (test code, extraneous utilities).  Adding these to your project will result in compile errors which I could not get rid of.  The only directory you need is the `glm/` directory; you can delete the `test/`, `util/`, `doc/`, and `bench/` directories.  If you were trying to follow ["How do I add OpenGL Mathematics (GLM) to Xcode 4?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779430/how-do-i-add-opengl-mathematics-glm-to-xcode-4) and were still having problems, this may be the thing which was tripping you up.
- The OpenGL Mathematics documentation tells you to include the  or  files.  In Xcode 4, you should include them like "glm.hpp" or "*.hpp".  Xcode will find the files no matter where in the project they are.  Supposedly you can add a user-defined build setting "USE_HEADERMAP" and set it to "NO" to disable this, but I didn't have any luck with that.
- And, just in case, note that your code files using the OpenGL Mathematics library *must* be Objective C++ files (ending in ".mm"), not the default/plain Objective C files (ending in ".m").  It is very much a C++ library after all... :-)

I hope that help.  I was just working through this myself, and I haven't had the chance to really push this (e.g. I've basically just added a `mat4` object or two and made sure things still compiled), but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I solved it remaning my `ViewController.m` to `ViewController.mm`. Change the extension to `.mm` tells **XCode** that the file may contain C++ code inside. The article [Write Object-C Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/WriteObjective-CCode/WriteObjective-CCode/WriteObjective-CCode.html) explains this in the *Classes and Objects* section.